# Invoke a stage repeatedly from another stage

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am currently writing a job that clones upstream docker images to my internal docker repo.
My job parameter page looks like

[image]

So it takes all the images and then generates the actual path on how it should look like

```
pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage('Create new image paths:tag'){
            steps {
                script {
                    params.IMAGES.split("\\r?\\n").each{ oldfullPath ->
                        def (path, tag) = oldfullPath.tokenize( ':' )
                        def app = path.tokenize('/')[-1]
                        println "App is ${app} and Tag is ${tag}"
                        switch(params.REPO) {
                            case "monitoring":
                                image = "eu.gcr.io/<PROJECT>/infra/monitoring"
                                break
                            case "apps":
                                image = "eu.gcr.io/<PROJECT>/infra/apps"
                                break
                        }
                        def newFullPath = "${image}/${app}:${tag}"
                        println "Full old image path is ${oldfullPath}"
                        println "Full new image path is ${newFullPath}"
                        // Pull and Push Image stage should be called here ! Using `${oldfullPath}` and `${newFullPath}`
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

As you can see, since i have multi line input, I have to use a loop to go through each line, get the app name and the tag and using `switch`, I generate the newpath. So for every iteration, I get `${oldfullPath}` and `${newfullPath}`

Now I need to pull and push these docker images. I do not want to leverage `dind`, so Im making using of Kaniko. And to pull and push an image, I can use something like this:

```
stage('Pull and Push Image') {
    agent {
        label "kaniko"
    }
    steps {
        container(name: 'kaniko', shell: '/busybox/sh') {
            withCredentials([
                string(credentialsId: 'infra', variable: 'PASS')
            ]) {
                withEnv(['PATH+EXTRA=/busybox:/kaniko']) {
                    sh """#!/busybox/sh
                    echo "FROM <OLD-IMAGE-PATH-COMES-HERE>" | \
                    /kaniko/executor \
                        --dockerfile /dev/stdin \
                        --destination <NEW-IMAGE-PATH-COMES-HERE>
                    """
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, this is a whole different stage. So i'm unsure of how can I call the `Pull and Push Image` stage repeatedly from the previous stage. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There's quite a bit to process here.

First, if you just want to copy Docker images over to your registry, this can be done as follows:

```
me@vm:~$ docker pull alpine:latest
latest: Pulling from library/alpine
89d9c30c1d48: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:c19173c5ada610a5989151111163d28a67368362762534d8a8121ce95cf2bd5a
Status: Downloaded newer image for alpine:latest
me@vm:~$ docker tag alpine:latest my-registry.my-company.io/alpine:latest
me@vm:~$ docker push my-registry.my-company.io/alpine:latest
The push refers to a repository [my-registry.my-company.io/alpine]
77cae8ab23bf: Pushed
latest: digest: sha256:e4355b66995c96b4b468159fc5c7e3540fcef961189ca13fee877798649f531a size: 528
```

Second, your parsing can be done inside the container in the loop, instead of in a separate step:

```
stage('Pull and Push Image') {
    agent {
        label "kaniko"
    }
    steps {
        container(name: 'kaniko', shell: '/busybox/sh') {
            withCredentials([
                string(credentialsId: 'infra', variable: 'PASS')
            ]) {
                withEnv(['PATH+EXTRA=/busybox:/kaniko']) {
                    // RUN THE LOOP HERE
                    script {
                    params.IMAGES.split("\\r?\\n").each{ oldfullPath ->
                        def (path, tag) = oldfullPath.tokenize( ':' )
                        def app = path.tokenize('/')[-1]
                        println "App is ${app} and Tag is ${tag}"
                        switch(params.REPO) {
                            case "monitoring":
                                image = "eu.gcr.io/<PROJECT>/infra/monitoring"
                                break
                            case "apps":
                                image = "eu.gcr.io/<PROJECT>/infra/apps"
                                break
                        }
                        def newFullPath = "${image}/${app}:${tag}"
                        println "Full old image path is ${oldfullPath}"
                        println "Full new image path is ${newFullPath}"

                    sh """#!/busybox/sh
                    echo "FROM ${oldfullPath}" | \
                    /kaniko/executor \
                        --dockerfile /dev/stdin \
                        --destination ${newFullPath}
                    """
              // adjust closing brackets as needed
```

This, of course, would be running the building sequentially on a single node, which may be just OK for you, or it may be not.

Now, let's assume that your real question is, "How do I start yet unknown number of parallel stages in declarative pipeline?"

The answer to this is, you can programmatically build your pipeline, like this:

```
images_array = ["quay.io/one", "docker.io/two", "docker.io/three"] // or split params as needed

def getBuilders()
{
    def builders = [:]

    images_array.eachWithIndex { it, index ->
        // name the stage
        def name = 'Build image #' + (index + 1)
        builders[name] = {
            stage (name) {
                def my_label = "kaniko" // can choose programmatically if needed
                node(my_label) {
                    timeout(time: 2, unit: 'HOURS') { 
                        try {
                            buildOneImage(it)
                        }
                        catch (err) { println "Failed to build ${it}"; throw err  }
                        finally {  }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
    return builders
}

def buildOneImage(old_path) {
   // replace path as needed, build image
   // use scripted-style pipeline, not the declarative one
}
```

And later in your main pipeline

```
        stage('Build all images') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def builders = getBuilders()
                    parallel builders
                }
            }
```